# Adding Multiple Columns from Multiple Tables to One column in a Query MYSQL

Tags: mysql

So just like the title says, I am trying to combine tables that have similar columns in a query. The result should be that i would have Division, Brigade, Regiment where regiment as 2 tables that can populate it. But i am having trouble combining the two table's columns to make that one column in the query. This is what i have tried:

```
SELECT d.name Division 
     , b.name Brigade
     , r.name Regiment
     , s.name Regiment
     , d.CO
     , b.FOB
     , r.Combatants 
  FROM ArmyDivision d
     , ArmyBrigade b
     , ArmyRegiment r
     , ArmySpecRegiment s 
 WHERE b.CO  = d.CO 
   AND b.FOB = r.FOB 
   AND d.CO  = s.CO
```

So r.name and s.name should be in the same column in the query under Regiment. I know this is wrong and it was a long shot. I have tried different variants of this but nothing, and google isnt very helpful as it is showing how to add columns from one table to another (not what i wanted). So basically, how would i do this efficiently?

Also, the data in AmrySpecRegiment does not have a brigade, just a division, so im assuming Brigade would be null for those entries. i dont know if this makes a different on how to do this query, but i figured might as well let you know.

Comment: Either you want both names in the same column, or you don't. Which is it?

Comment: i want both names in the same column, but each field in that column is either from specRegiment or from regiment, not concat the both

Comment: I think you're explaining it poorly. But depending on the nature of the problem, the solution can only be one of two possible types: Either use a UNION, or use LEFT [OUTER] JOIN and COALESCE(). For further help, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT d.name as Division, b.name as Brigade,r.name as Regiment,s.name as Regiment, d.CO, b.FOB, r.Combatants 
FROM ArmyDivision d 
INNER JOIN (ArmyBrigade b 
INNER JOIN ArmyRegiment r
ON b.FOB=r.FOB)
ON b.CO=d.CO
INNER JOIN ArmySpecRegiment s
ON d.CO = s.CO
```

INNER could be changed to LEFT if necessary

Also, to have multiple fields in one column, use CONCAT.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get the concatenated result of `r.name` and `s.name` column. In that case, you can use `CONCAT()` function like below. Also, notice that I have changed your old style implicit join syntax to ANSI92 style explicit join syntax.

```
select d.name as Division, 
b.name as Brigade,
CONCAT(r.name, ' ', s.name) as Regiment, 
d.CO, 
b.FOB, 
r.Combatants 
from ArmyDivision d 
join ArmyBrigade b on b.CO=d.CO
join ArmyRegiment r on b.FOB=r.FOB
join ArmySpecRegiment s on d.CO=s.CO;
```

Comment: no not concat, that would combine the regiment entries into one field, the values in regiment and specRegiment are unrelated in a sense that they are different regiment

Comment: @ShadowViper, In that case I think you are looking for `UNION`. But I can't just write down the query without knowing what's the desired result and table structure.

Answer (score 0):

Both columns you have extracted as "Regiment". As far as I know, you can't do this if you use the same name. 
If you use something like "r.name as Regiment_1,s.name as Regiment_2," That will bring the values to two columns.

When you say, you want both columns in one column, 
eg: We may have first_name and last_name in two columns. And now you want to get both column values to one column to display the whole name,

that can be done by this > SELECT CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) AS FullName;